# conemu задание путя к папке с .cmd скриптом

Tags: windows, conemu

Всем привет. Не могу вызвать npm.cmd из conemu.
путь к node прописан в PATH conemu и не содержит пробелов, при вводе комманды npm пишет, что это не является программой
Была попытка указать напрямую в настройках conemu путь и название программы, но результата нет.
прошу помочь

Comment: Как вызываете и что оно пишет в ответ?

Comment: npm вызываю. в переменной указано путь/к/нод/npm.cmd
в ответ получаю, что программа не найдена

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и укажите **конкретную** команду, как вы вводите её в консоли. И укажите конкретный путь до вашей папки с node.js. Это важно, т.к. ошибка скорее в вашем инпуте. Например, путь содержит пробелы, а вы не используете кавычки.

Comment: путь к нодам прописан. Пробелов нет. Сами ноды запускаються, но npm и npx нет

Comment: *путь к нодам прописан* - вопрос куда? В PATH? Если node положить в папку `c:\node` и вызвать команду `c:\node\npm.cmd` тоже не работает? А в виндовой консоли работает?

Comment: путь к node прописан в PATH conemu

Comment: А вот с диском С проблема: он почти полный. Поэтому я не могу туда накатить ноды

Comment: А почему не в PATH windows? Вместо диска С можно использовать любой другой. Суть в том, чтобы путь был максимально коротким, без пробелов и только на латинице, без всяких неожиданных символов. Вы же почему-то упорно не желаете привести в вопросе реальный путь и команду, которую вводите. Вот и гадания на кофейной гуще.

Comment: путь к нодам D:\Инстал\node если добавить программу в системную переменную, то нужно будет перезапускать ПК. это слишком долго так как на это уходит минуты 2

Comment: Ну вот и проблема - кириллица в путях. Нельзя было сразу это написать?

Comment: https://imgur.com/VjIldOv
вот скрин. даже с изменением папки node всё осталось на своих местах

Comment: Вы неправильно указали PATH в conemu. Должно быть `set "PATH=D:\node;%PATH%"`, а не так как у вас.

Comment: https://imgur.com/FuR6itZ

Comment: М, у меня вопрос: а для тебя есть принципиальная разница как ставить `npm`? Просто официальный установщик nodejs нормально себя везде прописывает и винда нормально всё всех дёргает после перезагрузки.

Comment: я диск С не хочу нагружать, а нпм ставится именно на него